# How to install and cron python3 Scrapy on cloud linux

Tags: python, linux, centos, scrapy, pip

I have a Scrapy spider written in python 3 and I want to run it as a cron job on my cloud Linux server (I have root access) 
first, I couldn't install using `pip3 install scrapy`, I faced :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1642, in bz2open
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/bz2.py", line 20, in <module>
    from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ImportError: No module named '_bz2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 582, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 543, in untar_file
    tar = tarfile.open(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1567, in open
    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1644, in bz2open
    raise CompressionError("bz2 module is not available")
tarfile.CompressionError: bz2 module is not available
```

then how can I run it as a cron job ?

Comment: Why people do not read error messages? It clearly states why it failed: `ImportError: No module named '_bz2'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named bz2 for Python 2.7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115280/importerror-no-module-named-bz2-for-python-2-7-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tarfile compressionerror bz2 module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646400/tarfile-compressionerror-bz2-module-is-not-available)